# How to verify presence of a modal dialog

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a webpage that has a button to download a file. Once clicking the button there appears a modal dialog popup which has no buttons for 'Ok' or 'Cancel' it is just informative dialog that says 'Generating the debuginfo file. Please wait.'. In my ui testing I need to check for the presence of that dialog. The html code for this modal dialog is as provided below. How should I check the presence of the dialog?

I have tried using Alert class and using `Alert(driver).switch_to.alert()` and `Alert(driver).dismiss()` and `accept()`
I have also tried

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_value")))
```

EDIT: edited to add actual code.

The html code for this element has following parameters:

```
     <div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="position: fixed; height: auto; width: 400px; top: 143px; left: 555.5px; display: block;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">
      <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
      <span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">Download debug info</span>
      <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
        <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">
        </span>
        <span class="ui-button-text">close</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 177px;">
      <br>Generating the debuginfo file. Please wait.</div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90;">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90;">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90;">

  </div>
```

Comment: Instead of the handcrafted HTML update the question with the actual HTML.

Comment: Added the actual code.

Comment: I can see the texts **Download debug info** and **Generating the debuginfo file. Please wait.** But I don't see the text **your download will begin...** within the HTML you have provided. Can you cross check once?

Comment: Sorry my bad. When I first posted the question I was not actually looking in the code. Updating my question once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is with a *Modal Dialog Box* so to locate and extract the element text **Generating the debuginfo file. Please wait.** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ui-dialog-content.ui-widget-content#dialog"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").split(">")[1])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content' and @id='dialog']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").split(">")[1])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. css_selector method worked for me. However when I use splitlines()[2] I get the error "IndexError: list index out of range" so I used splitlines()[1] and got TimeoutException.
Also without using splitlines I got the text returned as: <br>Generating the debuginfo file. Please wait. Is there a way to remove <br> tag?
Last question can we close the dialog when once we have detected it's presence? Currently the dialog is open until the download starts and then test is complete.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Also edited my comment above to include more info about the error.

Comment: @nd23 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Your updated solution worked with a slight change, I tried split(">")[1]  instead of index of 2. Thank you. Is there a way to close this modal once we have detected the innerHTML?

Comment: @nd23 Sounds great !!! Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please?